# Using observables to modify a list (or value) that has already been emitted

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

Imagine a UI that displays a list of cats. At a random interval between 0 and 3 seconds, one of three things happen:

- A cat's status is changed where status is one of ['sleeping', 'eating', 'purring']
- A cat is added to the list with a status of 'sleeping'
- A cat is removed from the list

These changes to the underlying model (cats list) should be reflected in the UI in real time.

Here is a link to a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-cats?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Is there an ideal solution to this using observables? One of my main challenges using observables is modifying a list that has already been emitted (or broadcast) without re-emitting the entire list.

Comment: Why you are not re-emitting list? Is there some performance problem? Even if you get a solution, this may be considered as bad practice.

Comment: Yes it is a performance problem. The list is huge and each item can be expensive to render. I would prefer not to re-render the entire list when I add an item to it. It is also a design problem in that I'm curious if this is something observables shouldn't be used for.

Comment: There is a `track-by`feature. It may help.

Comment: `track-by` link https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Comment: This helps with the performance aspect (assuming the view is recreated each time)

Comment: `One of my main challenges using observables is modifying a list that has already been emitted` what do you mean by this? Do you want to make a function which changes emitted `cat list` outside `observable`? Please explain your code requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scan` to hold the array and then each emission is going to be wrapped with an object representing each action:

```
enum ActionType {
  Add;
  Edit;
  Delete;
}

interface Action {
  type: ActionType;
  data
}

const action$ = new Subject<Action>();

const cats$ = action$
  .pipe(
    scan((cats, action) => {
      if (action.type === ActionType.Add) {
        cats.push(...);
      } else if (action.type === ActionType.Edit) {
        // edit from `cats`
      } else if (action.type === ActionType.Delete) {
        // remove from `cats`
      }
      return cats;
    }, []),
  )

action$.next({ type: ActionType.Add, data: { ... } });
```

You can also initialize the list of cats by passing an array to `scan`s second parameter instead of `[]`  (or you can make this another action).

Comment: When a new item is added to the list, the subject emits the entire list, right? Would it be possible to just append the new item to the already emitted list?